# Line Follower - How to detect 90 degree turns with 2 color sensors?

Tags: python

I'm building a line follower with EV3 lego kit as a school project. To stay on the line I'm using PID regulator which uses difference between 2 color sensors  on the front for calculating error (sensor read ranges from about 20 on black to 200 on white). It looks something like this:

[image: Line Follower]

The code I wrote works pretty well for smooth turns, even the sharp ones - but if the turn is a straight 90 degree angle something like this happens:

1. Robot starts the turn
2. It's not turning fast enough and both sensors end up on the black line
3. Error falls to zero as both sensors are reading same value from black
4. As the error is zero the robot goes straight and looses the line

I can manage make those turns by slowing speed and increasing integral and differential constants, but that makes control too aggressive and then it bounces left-right a lot, sometimes making one turn takes like 20 seconds before it manages to bounce like that to the straight line.

Any tips or tricks I could use to improve my Line Follower to deal better with those turns and overall?

[Here is my code on GitHub](https://github.com/Stormwaker/LineFollower/blob/master/line_follower.py) written with [Python API for ev3dev](https://ev3dev-lang.readthedocs.io/projects/python-ev3dev/en/stable/).

Comment: Do you have access to the absolute values in addition to their relative values?

Comment: @Acccumulation If you mean absolute values from each sensor then yes - r1 variable holds read from left and r2 from right.

Comment: When it turns, does it continue forward motion, or does it just pivot? And is more sensors an option?

Comment: @Acccumulation It turns slightly to the direction it was supposed to turn, because of the integral part, If I set integral high enough it can even return to the line sometimes, but other times it will just start making circles without reaching the line. I can only use 2 sensors.

Comment: It might help to draw a diagram for the right angle case. When you say that you end up with both sensors on the line, I take it that if you start going north and then the line turns east, the right sensor is on the line going east and the left sensor is on the line going north?

Comment: @Acccumulation It goes something like this: https://imgur.com/3kfezMS after both sensors are on black it starts to go straight and falls out of the line. Rights sensor leaves black slightly earlier and it starts to turn, but not fast enough.

Comment: The way you've drawn it, the distance between the sensors isn't much more than the thickness of the line. Is that the case, and do you have the option of making the sensors further apart?

Comment: @Acccumulation I could, but that results in worse results on other turns and straight line as it takes longer time to notice that the current course is incorrect and it's starting to bounce left-right for a while. Also if the right sensor would be close to the line during the start of the turn it would result in the same problem.